# error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No video id found"

Tags: node.js, discord.js, ytdl

Im currently creating my first discordjs bot and having some issues. I now want to add the functionality to play music but when I use the play command for my bot in my server I always get the error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No video id found".
I've googled it but there is no answer that helped me...
Here is the code:

```
async function execute(message, serverQueue, args) {

  const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
  if (!voiceChannel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
    );
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
  if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
    return message.channel.send(
      "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
    );
  }

  const songInfo = ytdl.getInfo(args);
  const song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
   };

  if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueContruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: 5,
      playing: true
    };

    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

    queueContruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = voiceChannel.join();
      queueContruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      return message.channel.send(err);
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
  }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
    
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could stop!");
    
  serverQueue.songs = [];
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
  if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
  }

  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
    .play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
  serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
}
```

Comment: `ytdl.getInfo()` expects a string- you passed an array

Comment: For future questions relating to *ytdl* include the `ytdl` tag

Answer (score -1):

The error means that somewhere in your code a `Promise` was rejected but you have not specified error handling for it. I am not sure which of your function calls return the Promise, but you need to add `.catch()` call to a promise when you need to handle an error.